# Procedimiento almacenado mysql Where In

Tags: mysql, sql

Alguien me podia ayudar a saber como realizar la siguiente consulta en un procedimiento almacenado , lo he intentado sin resultado , he leido que debe ser dinamico.

Dentro del In puede haber uno o n parametros

```
SELECT * FROM prueba.po
WHERE POC IN('1100869504','1100869506','1300890953','1300890954','1300890956')
```

Asi es mi procedimiento

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TempConf`(IN POR VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM prueba.po
WHERE POC IN(POR);
END
```

gracias

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Siempre son tres valores en el IN?, Que regla indica cuáles valores son los esperados?,

Comment: No , pueden ser 1 o n , lo determina el usuario

Answer (score 4):

Considera llevar a cabo los siguientes pasos para construir la solución:

- Ingresas el número de parámetros que deseas maneje el ***PA***
- Con la instrucción **`IS NULL`** verificas si el parámetro no tiene un valor ingresado
- Si por ejemplo para dicha consulta el usuario solo quiere ingresar un valor de referencia para la consulta entonces las demás posiciones de los parámetros que espera el OP deben declararse como **`NULL`**

**EJEMPLO**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testeo(IN valor1 INT, IN valor2 INT, IN valor3 INT)
BEGIN
    IF valor1 IS NULL AND valor2 IS NULL AND valor3 IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Se requieren mas parámetros de consulta';
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE columna IN(valor1, valor2, valor3);
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Entonces cuando lo invoquemos, si por ejemplo dejamos los tres parámetros como `NULL`:

```
CALL testeo(NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Nos devolvería un fallo como el siguiente:

> Error de SQL se requieren mas parámetros de consulta

En caso contrario Si le pasamos solo un valor y los demás los dejamos como `NULL`:

```
CALL testeo(1, NULL, NULL);
```

Nos daría un resultado como este:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4  Col5
"1"  "alan" "1"  "1"   "1"
```

Es decir:

> Si no deseas pasar ningún valor entonces debes colocar el valor **`NULL`** por cada posición de cada parámetro establecido, en cambio si vas a pasar solo 1 o n valores entonces todas las demás posiciones que NO ocupes se deben declarar como **`NULL`** dando el dinámismo de construir una consulta que retorna datos dependiendo de la cantidad de valores que el usuario pasa cuando invoca el PA.

Comment: El problema es que no siempre se reciben 3 pueden ser 3 o 100, por eso lo declare como Varchar para recibir una cadena es decir 'valor1','valor2','valor3','valorN' sin embargo no he podido lograr que cconsulte la cadena como lo hago  en el primer ejemplo

Comment: @AntonioTesillo revisa el enlace siguiente igual te da una aproximación a lo que buscas, pues lo veo un poco complejo: [enlace útil](https://federico-razzoli.com/variable-number-of-parameters-and-optional-parameters-in-mysql-mariadb-procedures)

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Comment: @Aprendiz confieso que soy fán de sus respuesta, siempre reviso su actividad, gracias por sus aportes a la comunidad.

Comment: Hola @J.Rodríguez te agradezco mucho el comentario

Comment: @Aprendiz de nada, para eso estamos, valoro mucho el esfuerzo que hacemos los usuarios para ayudar a salir de apuros a los demás, Saludos Cordiales!